# Thermal properties of chemical compounds

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics

I have a chemistry related question, I'm doing a research on some inorganic salts (KOH, KCl) and similar compounds and I'm struggling finding the thermal properties like (thermal conductivity, specific heat, coefficient of thermal expansion, kinematic viscosity, density, latent heat of fusion, melting point), I could find some but not all, can you help me in this

Comment: You can check the MSDS of the compounds.

Comment: MSDS will not have the information, except the melting point and density if they were liquids. Please clarify your question and give a context of your question. Do you have access to SciFinder? How can solids like KOH and KCl have kinematic viscosity?

Comment: Tell others where you were searching, not to repeat your actions.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the data you want to access are available for free, others are available on purchase of reference materials and subscription of databases typically seen in *research libraries* and institutes.  Get in touch with your supervisor and libraries close to universities; it depends on their contracts with the publishers if access already is granted by your affiliation with a research group, or permissible as a *walk-in user*.

This being said, for some chemicals you find properties listed in the property boxes on wikipedia ([example KOH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_hydroxide)), or in the [NIST Chemistry WebBook](https://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/) (again [example KOH](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Formula=KOH&NoIon=on&Units=SI&cTC=on)).  A handy (somewhat handy) reference equally is the [CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRC_Handbook_of_Chemistry_and_Physics) you either access [on-line](https://hbcp.chemnetbase.com/faces/contents/ContentsSearch.xhtml) (requires a subscription, some groups/schools/libraries have), or browse through the heavy print edition.  (With their virtual library card, there are a couple of editions on [archive.org](https://archive.org/search.php?query=CRC+Chemistry+Physics&sin=) one can borrow online for 14 days, too.)

As `@AChem` already indicated in a comment, you would complement the fact retrieval with a consultation of a professional database.  In addition to SciFinder (by the American Chemical Society), I recommend Reaxys (by Elsevier) because it inherited so many data of the [Gmelin handbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmelin_database).  As your search includes `thermal expansion`, `viscosity`, etc. possibly your research is in solid state chemistry (e.g., KOH as a flux/melt, [example](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10948-020-05675-z)); well, then ask for [Springer Materials](https://materials.springer.com/) (because of the tables and phase diagrams once compiled in Landolt-Börnstein).  All three electronic databases require a paid subscription.

Comment: Although I like Reaxys (for the same reasons you mentioned Gmelin and Beilstein inherited data), but even many Tier-1 universities in USA do not have access to it-maybe it is too expensive. Also, SciFinder has recently changed. It has become SciFinder-n, after incorporating millions of abstracts from *Chemische Zentralblatt* (among other changes).

Comment: @AChem This pattern may happen anywhere, to any database. My awareness of *walk-in user* as a legal term is personal experience: compile my questions & of colleagues on paper, take the train, query Thieme's Science of Synthesis in a different school, with clearance -- because thanks to encouragement by Zass and Braendle (ETHZ), the methods of Houben-Weyl print were scanned and linked to modern references. So while there was training in Beilstein Crossfire & STN already as undergrad in France, the catalysis folks in the US couldn't believe how to work without SoS on PC, only few knew Reaxys.

Comment: Interesting, I think Reaxys is more popular in Europe. I hope one day major German works will be (machine) translated into English. MT has become quite reliable. A typical US graduate student does not even know about these names: Houben-Weyl, Beilstein, Gmelin etc.

Comment: Yeah; «you know Beilstein, you were in Europe; you know SoS, you were in the US» And as SciFinder is so expensive, our school holds 2 FTE (max), though already participating in a consortium with other schools. Access to Reaxys equally is more often constrained now (once access all across campus, now only to *the* groups), too. Are ACS' activities still all under IRC 501(c)(3), as are the Ivies? For some time, Elsevier's ROIs exceeded those of Apple (well in the double digit percentage); not only for Reaxys, but incl. for journal fees hurting all from the west (like UC Berkely) to East Europe.

Comment: @AChem The Beilstein English <-> German dictionary, by the way: http://web.stanford.edu/group/swain/beilstein/index.html (open access)

Comment: This is sad how publishing houses are charging like crazy. They don't pay a penny to review or write articles with the exception of encyclopedia chapters. They offer about $250 for a single contribution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141715/discussion-between-buttonwood-and-achem).